# Graph adjacency list giving wrong output

Tags: graph-theory, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

I have made a simple code to take number of vertices and number of edges as input, the take each edge and add it to the list of that vertex. However, I m not getting it right.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        int n,m; // number of vertices and edges
        cin>>n>>m;
        list<int> a[n];
        list<int>::iterator it;
        while(m--) {
            int x,y;
            cin>>x>>y; // one edge x & y are vertices 
            a[x-1].push_back(y-1);    // -1 because it array is 0 index based
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(it= a[i].begin();it!=a[i].end();it++) {
                cout<<*it<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Let say my input test case is:

```
1
3 3 // number of edges and vertices
1 2
2 3
3 1
```

Expected output should be:

```
2 3
1 2
2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        int n,m;
        cin>>n>>m;
        list<int> a[n];
        list<int>::iterator it;
        while(m--) {
            int x,y;
            cin>>x>>y;
            a[x-1].push_back(y);
            a[y-1].push_back(x);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(it= a[i].begin();it!=a[i].end();it++) {
                cout<<*it<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```